# linq to sql one-one relationship C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

It is necessary that after the creation of records in the table "Clients" took up ID. Later ID used to create a new entry in the "Clients_details".

```
        var user = GetUsers();
        var userdet = GetclientsDetails();

        string hashedpass = getMd5Hash(UIPassword.Text);

        var newreg = new Clients
        {
            login = UILogin.Text,
            password = hashedpass,
            subscribeid = Convert.ToInt32(UIId.Text)
        };

        user.InsertOnSubmit(newreg);
        user.Context.SubmitChanges();

        var details = new Clients_details
        {
            city = UICity.Text,
            first_name = UIFirst_name.Text,
            last_name = UIFamiliya.Text,
            name = UIName.Text,
            Clients = newreg
        };

        userdet.InsertOnSubmit(details);
        userdet.Context.SubmitChanges();
```

After this code fails:
**"An attempt was made to perform an operation Attach or Add in relation to an object that is not new, and possibly loaded from another DataContext. This operation is not supported."**

[image: DBML]

How to properly create a record that does not appear a mistake? Thank you!

```
    private static Table<Clients> GetUsers()
    {
        var dce = new BaseDBMLDataContext();
        return dce.Clients;
    }

    private static Table<Clients_details> GetclientsDetails()
    {
        var dce = new BaseDBMLDataContext();
        return dce.Clients_details;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `userdet.Context` and `user.Context` was built using a different `dataContext` and that needs to be created using the same dataContext rather than instantiating a new one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have added the above code. How can I combine the datacontext's?

Comment: you should reactor your code and use the same instance of the DataContext instead of creating a new one

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to only call the SubmitChanges only once in the end, and also you need to make sure the user and userdet you are using share the same context

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly states, you're using different contexts (user and userdet) for each entity to add. You should have one DataContext and use that one to add the entities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes looks like you're using two different instances of the same context:

```
user.Context.SubmitChanges();
userdet.Context.SubmitChanges();
```

A good approach to build up your entities should be something like :

```
//Create your client details entity
var details = new Clients_details
{
    city = UICity.Text,
    first_name = UIFirst_name.Text,
    last_name = UIFamiliya.Text,
    name = UIName.Text    
};

//Create your client entity
var newreg = new Clients
{
    login = UILogin.Text,
    password = hashedpass,
    subscribeid = Convert.ToInt32(UIId.Text),
    //Assigning the details entity (FK) to the client
    ClientDetails = details
};

//Saving both the client and its details
user.InsertOnSubmit(newreg);
user.Context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'vasilevalex_26.dbo.Clients_details'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated. 
 =((

Comment: Feor please try to structure your questions/comment before posting them.Thanks. Btw in this case if the Id column on your table is a PK with identity (as I assume it should be) then you cannot assign a value to Id.

Comment: I'm trying to execute your code. Table ID in the same detail should be the same as in the "clients". I did it in the field of PK to do. On this I can not do ...